# Problems of finding some devices with Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement Bluetooth Low Energy . The fact is, I can find some devices around me, so the scanning seems working, but there are some devices which I can't find ... such as a motorola, which has Android API 19, so since BLE is enabled since API 18, shouldn't it work ?

So my question is, are there some devices not compatible with BLE ? (I can found some devices but not all)

Comment: BLE supports has to be hardware supported AND software supported. If you Motorola does not have e BLE chip, but only a "classical" Bluetooth chip, that's normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer !

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "device"? Motorola what? Phone? Watch? Light bulb?

If your phone can search for and find some ble enabled devices then it got both hw and sw support.
The other "device" must be ble advertising for your phone to hear it during scanning.
A Motorola phone with android api19 can only scan, not advertise. Some android 5 devices can do ble advertise, so they can be scanned by android api19 devices but not the other way round.